# Помогите правильно составить предложение и помогите с запятыми, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

Организационная структура ГЭПП «НИЖЕГОРОДОБЛКОММУНЭНЕРГО» рассмотрена, численность специалистов в количестве 15 человек для организации в 2016 году считаем достаточной.

Answer (score 2):

"Численность в количестве..." - неверное (тавтологичное) выражение, поскольку оба эти понятия выражаются числом (правильно: "специалисты в количестве 15 человек", "численность или численный состав специалистов - 15 человек"). Возможные варианты:

> ... (намеченную/предложенную) численность специалистов в 2016 году (15
>   человек) считаем достаточной для организации.
>
> ... 15 специалистов в 2016 году считаем достаточным для организации
>   численным составом.
>
> ... 15 человек считаем достаточным для организации в 2016 году
>   количеством специалистов.